# Transiting in KL on tickets bought separately

Tags: transit, kul

My three children who are studying in Manila are planning to visit home in Sri Lanka in June. We are all Sri Lankan passport holders.

Since the airline that's best for us does not have a sector for one booking, the children will have to check out and check in their luggage in Kuala Lumpur.

In order to check out and check in luggage they will have to go through immigration. Do they need to have some kind of a transit visa?

Comment: Check with your airlines. Often baggage can still be sent directly, also if your children have different tickets (for different segments).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi You seem to be focusing on the baggage question. I believe the question is whether the children will have to have transit visas.